# Random mongo shutdown

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I had mongo randomly shutdown on one of my servers today and I was wondering if anyone could take a look at the logs below and tell me what might have happened. The server is hosted on digital ocean but there seems to be a number of odd ip's trying to connect before the server went down.

```
Sun Jun 14 06:42:13.027 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57440 #48 (7 connections now open)
Sun Jun 14 06:42:13.027 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57441 #49 (8 connections now open)
Sun Jun 14 06:42:13.027 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57442 #50 (9 connections now open)
Sun Jun 14 06:42:13.027 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57443 #51 (10 connections now open)
Sun Jun 14 08:26:29.103 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 7ms
Mon Jun 15 04:56:19.810 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 184.105.247.195:44313 #52 (11 connections now open)
Mon Jun 15 04:56:19.950 [conn52] end connection 184.105.247.195:44313 (10 connections now open)
Mon Jun 15 04:56:40.737 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 184.105.247.195:52328 #53 (11 connections now open)
Mon Jun 15 04:56:40.809 [conn53] end connection 184.105.247.195:52328 (10 connections now open)
Mon Jun 15 08:00:01.940 [conn50] remove scottwio.tweets ndeleted:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 1 locks(micros) w:181995 183ms
Tue Jun 16 02:22:39.000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 52.28.2.57:45022 #54 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 02:22:39.013 [conn54] end connection 52.28.2.57:45022 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 02:22:39.466 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 52.28.2.57:45039 #55 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 02:22:45.578 [conn55] end connection 52.28.2.57:45039 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:07:28.573 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 169.54.233.118:21188 #56 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:07:59.589 [conn56] end connection 169.54.233.118:21188 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:15:29.197 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 184.105.247.195:47712 #57 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:15:29.337 [conn57] end connection 184.105.247.195:47712 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:15:48.188 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 184.105.247.195:53870 #58 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:15:48.273 [conn58] end connection 184.105.247.195:53870 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 21:20:38.214 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 74.82.47.3:53219 #59 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 21:20:38.339 [conn59] end connection 74.82.47.3:53219 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 21:20:56.436 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 74.82.47.3:60827 #60 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 21:20:56.505 [conn60] end connection 74.82.47.3:60827 (10 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 06:25:58.255 [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:55958 (9 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 06:25:58.255 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:55955 (9 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 06:25:58.255 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:55954 (9 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 06:25:58.255 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:55957 (9 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 06:25:58.255 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:55956 (9 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 08:00:00.976 [conn47] end connection 127.0.0.1:57439 (4 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 08:00:00.976 [conn48] end connection 127.0.0.1:57440 (3 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 08:00:00.976 [conn49] end connection 127.0.0.1:57441 (2 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 08:00:00.976 [conn50] end connection 127.0.0.1:57442 (2 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 08:00:00.977 [conn51] end connection 127.0.0.1:57443 (2 connections now open)


***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.020 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=820 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=scottwio
Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.020 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.8
Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.020 [initandlisten] git version: a350fc38922fbda2cec8d5dd842237b904eafc14
Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.020 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.020 [initandlisten] options: { fork: true, logappend: true, logpath: "/root/Sites/logs/mongo" }
Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.031 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
```

Comment: Did the "server" shut down, or did it just drop the connection to mongo? If it's the latter, that happens occasionally, and if you're using an existing mongodb module, it should be able to handle re-establishing a connection automatically before continuing with database operations. It looks like there was an hour of inactivity during the restart, so that doesn't really point to malicious activity or the result of an error.

Comment: It looks like a question for http://serverfault.com